# Can I embed a vpython on an html page?

Tags: html, embed, vpython

I have been learning vpython, and I am making a lunar lander copy for a school project. I was wondering if there is any way to embed a vpython canvas or window on a webpage. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At glowscript.org you can export your program to JavaScript and embed it in a web page. On the page where you edit your GlowScript VPython progrm, click "Shae or export this program". However, because at glowscript.org your Python code is transpiled to JavaScript, you can't import arbitrary Python modules.